# Wall broadcast message in terminal to desktop popup message?

Tags: libnotify

I'll receive a `wall` broadcast message like this in my terminal:

```
Broadcast message from rick@dell (somewhere) (Tue Jun 23 19:21:32 2020):       
                                                                               
If no activity, shutdown in: 15 minute(s).
```

Can a job be running on my machine that watches my terminal screen for messages like this and issue a desktop popup bubble message with libnotify send?

The message may have already scrolled off the screen if a batch job is running.

I know I can install ssh server on my local machine and the server/remote host can issue libnotify sends instead of `wall` broadcasts but that isn't my first choice. I also know I can use `nc` (netcast) but that is less appealing.